# How does QVideoFilterRunnable and OpenGL Context works together?

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es, qml

I'm trying to program an augmented reality (AR) app with C++, Qt, QML, OpenCV and OpenGL on Android.

Principle workflow:

1. The camera supplies a new videoframe (with openGL texture ID)
2. I capture this frin `QVideoFilterRunnable::run(...)`
3. Then I make some object recognition and calculate the new position
   (inside the videoframe) where I need to put objects in the 3D opengl
   scene
4. Render the openGL object newly
5. Bring it in the openGL rendering pipeline (fixed function or compatibility profile) TOGETHER with the videoframe as a background texture (zero copy) to maximise the render speed

Code example to manipulate the videoframe texture:

```
QVideoFrame FilterRunnable::run(QVideoFrame* input, 
                                const QVideoSurfaceFormat &sFormat,
                                RunFlags flags) 
{
    if(sFormat.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer::GLTextureHandle)
    {
        QOpenGLContext* c = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();
        QOpenGLFunctions* f = c->functions();

        GLuint textID = input->handle().toInt();
        f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textID);

        float pixels[] = {
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        };

        f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);

        f->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                        0, GL_RGB, 
                        2, 2, 0, 
                        GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);
    }
}
```

With `glTexImage2D()` the screen becomes black whithout any error.

The problem is that I did't find any infos how `FilterRunnable::run()` handles the OpenGL context in the background. I don't know how using `glDrawArrays()`, `glViewport()` without the standard functions `initializeGL()`, `resizeGL()`, `paintGL()`.

For example, I want to combine the videoframe (mapped on a background polygon) together with arbitrary OpenGL objects in front of it.

Where I can get info regarding this topic or what is the best way?